# Redirect to external link inside a nav tag in html

Tags: html, nav

It might be a stupid question, but I cannot find the answer to it (or I am using wrong keywords).

I have the following simple navigation structure:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li> -->
        <li><a href="www.twitter.com" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Now when I click on the 'twitter' item I am not redirected to the actual website, but I just get the "twitter.com" appended to my current link.

Is this a limitation of the `nav` tag?

I also tried to use the `target="_blank"` but still no effect.

How would you achieve something like that? Use `menu` instead of `nav`?

Comment: you forgot "http://" in the href of the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li> -->
        <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

You need to tell the browser which protocal to use. In this case you want to add `http://` or `https://` to the URL to tell the browser that you want to naviget to a URL and not an anchor on the current page

Answer (score 0):

try adding: http:// in front of your link so you'll have:

```
 <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com"
```

This will load a new website url rather than look for 'twitter.com' in your domain.

But add:

```
target="_blank"
```

to load in a new window rather than over your website

Answer (score 0):

Please use either http:// or https:// if the link is external

```
<li><a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
```

or

```
 <li><a href="https://www.twitter.com" target="_blank" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li> --&gt;
       <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```